# Refrehing recyclerview data after resumed from another activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two activities . In first activity i have a recyclerview I load the recyclerview data from web service. When i back pressed from second activity  the recyclerview data has to be refreshed with updated data from server. Can anyone help?

Comment: you should load data in onResume method again

Comment: I already tried that solution but could not get a result. Because when application runs in background calling activity from background the method inside onResume calls again. The method no need to be call again.

Comment: paste your code

Comment: please post some relevant codes first, also what is your plan to refresh your data without fetching from server?

Answer (score 1):

use onResume() method of the activity
whenever the comes in foreground onResume() is called unlike onCreate()
which is called only once(when activity is created)

so move the code to set recycler adapter(and corresponding query to create list or query db) in onResume()
it will reload every time you come back to activity

Answer (score 0):

in onResume method

```
  arrayList.clear();
    arrayList.addAll(//your data here);
```

and then

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```